# How do I find out the number of elements in a Javascript array?

Tags: javascript, arrays

In the ECMAScript specification, `array.length` is not defined as the number of elements in an array.

http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/#sec-properties-of-array-instances-length

> The length property of an Array instance is a data property whose value is always numerically greater than the name of every configurable own property whose name is an array index.

That is, a Javascript engine could cause `array.length` to be positive infinity in all cases, and it would be compliant with the standard.

Taking this into account, how should I count the elements in an array?

Comment: From what I understand from your question, you're concerned that someone would overwrite the `array.length` property. Is that correct? If so then just use any `forEach` like @RedMercury explained or `for in` to loop over your array and corollary count the length.

Comment: At least Chrome rejects setting `array.length` to Infinity: `Uncaught RangeError: Invalid array length`.

Comment: It's very much a theoretical concern: I'm aware that in practice, array.length has a very strong relationship to the number of elements in the array.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's not the only specification of the `length` property.

The specification of the abstract operation [`ArrayCreate(length, proto)`](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/#sec-arraycreate) says that the `length` property is initialized to the `length` parameter.

And the specification of [Array Exotic Objects](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/#sec-array-exotic-objects) explains how it's updated:

> Specifically, whenever an own property is added whose name is an array index, the value of the length property is changed, if necessary, to be one more than the numeric value of that array index

Other array manipulations are defined in terms of these operations, so the `length` property should accurately reflect the indexes of array elements.

Answer (score 1):

What? Just use `array.length`. Im sure there exists no implementation of the standards that set the length of an array to positive infinity.

If for some reason you really want to avoid using `array.length`, just use `forEach`.

```
var arrLength = 0;
arr.forEach(function() {
  arrLength++
})
```

Comment: In a way, wrong: `var x = [9]; x.length = 10;` and your function iterate 10 times, not 1. Also, `var y = [9, 10, 14]; y.length = 1; console.log(y);` shows only `[9]`.

Comment: @Seb that's actually wrong on both accounts for the `x` array the above would give you `arrLength` of `1`. As for the `y` array, setting the length of the array lower _truncates_ it. You are indeed deleting the values `10` and `14` from it because you are saying there is a single item in the array.

Comment: My bad, I didn’t check it. But `.shift()` and `.pop()` will produce different outcome.

Comment: @Seb well, they do because increasing the length of the array also...well increases the array. Only it doesn't really. For a lot of intents and purposes `var x = []; x.length = 10;` will be (or act like) an array that has 10 items in it all of which are `undefined`. However, stuff like `forEach` or `map` do not actually go over the unset slots, hence why @RedMercury's code will not give you the same number as `.length`. A similar thing can be observed if you do, say, `var x = []; x[9] = 1;` - you will get an array with `length` of 10 but the `forEach` count there will give you `1`.

Comment: @Vld, yes, you’re right. This makes this solution very valid. Luckily I haven’t encountered such use of `length` in arrays in my line of work.

Comment: Well, the only reason I've seen for setting the length is to create an empty array of some big size. Say, if you want an array for a thousands items or something. It's technically equivalent to doing `var x = new Array(1000)` (you can also omit `new` for this). According to some performance measures I've seen setting `length` is faster than the constructor function, but other ones have shown the opposite. I've never really looked much into it because the only reason I've had to initialise a big array is to generate a string like so `Array(251).join("a")` for a 250 character long string.

Answer (score 0):

Changing `.length` property is prevented by Chrome. Run this:

```js
var x = [];
x.length = +Infinity; // Uncaught RangeError: Invalid array length
```

So, luckily, no risk here. `For` looping throught Infinity. Probably would end somewhat earlier due to some end of memory.

But still, it is possible to change `length` just like that. What will happen if we make it bigger?

```js
var x = [9];
console.log(x); // [9]

x.length = 10;
console.log(x); // still [9], although length is 10 this time

// example from Red Mercury
x.forEach(function (item, index) {
    console.log('Item', index, item);
});
  
// will print: Item 0 9
  
// But...
do {
    console.log(x.shift());
} while(x.length > 0); // .shift() and .pop() update .length property

// will print 9 once, and nine times undefined
// probably the same with .pop(), just in reversed order
```

And the smaller?

```js
var x = [9, 10, 14];
console.log(x); // [9, 10, 14]

x.length = 1;
console.log(x); // [9]

// example from Red Mercury
x.forEach(function (item, index) {
    console.log('Item', index, item);
  });
  
// will print: Item 0 9
  
// But...
do {
    console.log(x.shift());
} while(x.length > 0);

// will print only 9
```

So while bigger length can be checked with `.forEach()` the smaller cannot. It is not recommended to tamper with length value (because `.forEach()` and `.shift()` start to “desynchronize”), but in your own code this should not happen to you. I don’t think that language should be that totally bulletproof, nor that it’s possible. Reality will check it in the end with script breaking in a browser, and that could limit programmers too much. If JavaScript would have proper array, not just array like objects, that would be prevented but it is what it is.